# Parse output and fetch hex colors

Tags: regex, string, go

I have the output of an ImageMagick command to compute the top few entries of the image histogram, which is this:

```
416327: ( 61, 65, 39) #3D4127 srgb(61,65,39)
212997: (130,127, 83) #827F53 srgb(130,127,83)
428312: (167,161, 99) #A7A163 srgb(167,161,99)
481351: (198,187,116) #C6BB74 srgb(198,187,116)
381013: (214,200,148) #D6C894 srgb(214,200,148)
```

It represents the most dominant colors of an image and now I want to "extract" these colors and store them in a struct so I can make use of them in the rest of my Go code. Now I'm struggling about how to do this?

First, I though about using `fmt.Sscanf`, but I only want to extract two fields, the first one and the #XXXXXX. Can you point me in the correct directtion?

So for example, the first line should result in

```
416327 #3D4127
```

Comment: Please show your current attempt, and describe the problems you're having with it.

Comment: `^(\d{6})[^#]*(#[A-F0-9]{6}).*$` ... then use the first and second capture groups.

Comment: In Imagemagick piping the output to sed, you can do:    `convert image -format "%c" histogram:info: | while read line; do echo $line | sed -n 's/^\(.*\):.*\(#.*\) .*$/\1 \2\n/p'; done`     Since this was on hold, I could not give a proper answer with an example.

Comment: The question seems straightforward to me. It has two parts. The first is how to extract the two fields from the list of data. I have answered that above. The second is putting the results into some structure. That I cannot answer as I do not know what kind of structure. Putting it into an array is easy. `array=$(convert image -format "%c" histogram:info: | while read line; do echo $line | sed -n 's/^\(.*\):.*\(#.*\) .*$/\1 \2\n/p'; done)`  But that may not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
^(\d{6})[^#]+(#\S+)

Where group 1 contains first 6 digit
and group 2 contains the hash value
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pWcp1l/1)

Update Based on OP's comment:

```
^(\d+)[^#]+(#\S+)
```

or

```
^(\d{6,100})[^#]+(#\S+)
```

If the starter digit is not limited to 6 digit then replace `\d{6}`  with `\d+` ( which means one or more digit) or in case you know the range then you do : `\d{min,max}`  e.g `\d{6,100}`

Sample Source ([run here](https://ideone.com/zcmXf2) ):

```
func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)^(\d{6})[^#]+(#\S+)`)
    var str = `416327: ( 61, 65, 39) #3D4127 srgb(61,65,39)
212997: (130,127, 83) #827F53 srgb(130,127,83)
428312: (167,161, 99) #A7A163 srgb(167,161,99)
481351: (198,187,116) #C6BB74 srgb(198,187,116)
381013: (214,200,148) #D6C894 srgb(214,200,148)

`
segs2 := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)
for i := 0; i < len(segs2); i++ {
    fmt.Println(segs2[i][1], "," ,segs2[i][2]);
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that histogram counts are not limited to 6 characters. The number of counts depends upon the size of the image and how frequently that color is being used.

Comment: Updated the answer a bit as per your comment, let me know if that works for you... if so, then you may accept the answer as well

Comment: That was my comment, but I am not the OP. But that does fix the issue that I mentioned with more elegant regex than my sed command.